# RxSwift: Subscribe to Observable.zip. Handle result as tuple?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to combine two network requests with the `zip` function. These two requests rely on another one (getInfoA).

This is the code I'm working with:

```
IoC.networkProcessService.getInfoA(with: identifier)
            .map { infoA -> Observable<(InfoB, InfoC)> in

                return Observable.zip(
                    IoC.networkProcessService.getInfoB(with: infoA),
                    IoC.networkProcessService.getInfoC(with: infoA) 
                { return ($0, $1) }

            }
            .subscribe(onNext: { result in
                print(result)

               // result is of type Observable<(InfoB, InfoC)>...

            }, onError: { error in
                Logger.main.log(category: [.network, .error], arguments: error.localizedDescription)

            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I would expect that `result` (in the `subscribe` block) is a tuple and that I'm able to access `infoB` and `infoC`.

But it's not. Is `subscribe` the right operator to access the tuple from `zip`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `map` to `flatMap`, `result` will change to tuple instead Observable.

```
IoC.networkProcessService.getInfoA(with: identifier)
  .flatMap { infoA -> Observable<(InfoB, InfoC)> in

    return Observable.zip(
      IoC.networkProcessService.getInfoB(with: infoA),
      IoC.networkProcessService.getInfoC(with: infoA)
      { return ($0, $1) }

  }
  .subscribe(onNext: { result in
    print(result)

    // result is of type (InfoB, InfoC)

  }, onError: { error in
    Logger.main.log(category: [.network, .error], arguments: error.localizedDescription)

  })
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: I still struggle with flatmap vs map on Observables... thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem Try hard